# Bundle is invalid with a very strange high number. How to get rid of it?

Tags: ios, fastlane, visual-studio-app-center

When trying to upload the latest greatest app version of our app to App Store Connect we are getting the following error: This bundle is invalid. The value for key CFBundleShortVersionString [2.1.0] in the Info.plist file must contain a higher version than that of the previously approved version [1565960106]. I understand that you cannot upload version 1.0 after 2.0, but in our case we're not planning to make our version higher than 1565960106. How can we get rid of this strange high number?

Side note: the store version is 2.0, there is indeed a faulty version where the build number was used as version number and that one was approved for external testers, but never released to the store.